# What is the minimum and maximum value of lodash/debounce

Tags: reactjs, lodash, debouncing

Can anyone tell me what is the minimum and maximum values we can use for `debounce` in react js?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had to guess from the [source code](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/debounce.js#L88)

```
maxWait = maxing ? Math.max(+options.maxWait || 0, wait) : maxWait
```

Looks like the minimum is `0`, and the maximum is probably [Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER), or `9007199254740991`

> The **`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`** constant represents the maximum safe
> integer in JavaScript (`2^53 - 1`).

Notice the above doesn't explicitly preclude negative `maxWait` or `wait` values, but since `debounce` uses a `setTimeout` [under the hood](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/debounce.js#L107) though, anything less than 0 doesn't really make any sense, i.e. it can't be debounced into the past. Note, however, that `setTimeout` is throttled to a minimum of once every 4ms.

[Reasons for delays longer than specified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified)

So a tighter min-max bound may *actually* be `[4, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER]`